# How to translate "rape"?

Tags: word-usage

Committing rape is generally rendered in the E-o texts I read by "perforto", or "seksperforto".  This formula just falls too flat on my ears.  There is a beautiful and telling E-o root-verb, trudi, which means imposing or intruding something onto others or into something.  Why not rendering raping by trudago (intruding action) or more explicitly sekstrudo?

More esperantistically I would also propose malamori ("making un-love") as the thing most opposite to making love.

Comment: I guess unless "malamori" was an already established word for "rape" (which it doesn't seem to be), you'd risk it being misinterpreted as being in a platonic relationship and/or being sexually abstinent / celibate.

Comment: Also, as sex can be more than just intercourse, rape (forced sex) can therefore be something other than only exactly forced intercourse. And even in the case of heterosexual intercourse, what if the rapist is the woman?

Comment: This isn't really a question, as you answer it by yourself: 'rape' is _(seks)perforto_ in Esperanto. I suggest you reword the question into something like whether there are other words for 'rape' than the established one. Right now it is a question misused as means of proposing a private new word.

Answer (score 3):

In Bulgarian (изнасилване), Dutch (verkrachten) and German (vergewaltigen) the root meaning in fact is `perforti`. So `seksperforti` is fine. Note that also other language use prescriptive words with roots like in `violate`.

The etymologie of `rape` is latin and carries the meaning of seize by force. Like for instace `vergewaltigen` the sex related meaning is the main one.